# xStream problems - How to deserialize undeclared attributes

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm using xStream to deserialize XML.

My xml contains a tag:

```xml
<Element Name="Test" Value="TestValue" Tag="tag" Text.Color="Red"/>
```

and class

```java
public class Element {

   @XStreamAsAttribute
   public String Name;

   @XStreamAsAttribute
   public String Value;

   public Map<String, String> AnyAttr = new HashMap<String, String>();   
}
```

fields Name and Value deserialize correct,

How can I deserialize undeclared fields (Tag, Text.Color) to my map ( Map AnyAttr )?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [`Converter`](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/Converter.html). That's the only way, you can't achieve this with simple configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom Converter class. Like this one:

```
public class ElementConverter implements Converter
{
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return Element.class == clazz;
    }

    public void marshal(Object object, HierarchicalStreamWriter hsw, MarshallingContext mc) {
        Element e = (Element) object;
        hsw.addAttribute("Name", e.Name);
        hsw.addAttribute("Value", e.Value);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : e.AnyAttr.entrySet())
        {
            hsw.addAttribute(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader hsr, UnmarshallingContext uc) {
        Element e = new Element();
        String key;
        int count = hsr.getAttributeCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            key = hsr.getAttributeName(i);
            if (key.equals("Name")) e.Name = hsr.getAttribute(i);
            else
            if (key.equals("Value")) e.Value = hsr.getAttribute(i);
            else e.AnyAttr.put(key, hsr.getAttribute(i));
        }
        return e;
    }
}
```

and then you have to register converter in XStream before you use it:

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.aliasType("Element", Element.class);
    xstream.registerConverter(new ElementConverter());
```